# How to give a column in the Django admin change_list a CSS class

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to change the column widths in the list display of the Django admin.

Is it possible somehow to add a CSS classname to a column?
I'd preferably not overwrite the entire template to accomplish this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Django >= 1.6, CSS classes are included with list_display output:

"*The field names in `list_display` will also appear as CSS classes in the HTML output, in the form of `column-<field_name>` on each `<th>` element. This can be used to set column widths in a CSS file.*"

Comment: Fun. I actually added that commit in Django during the last sprint. Great to see it getting used already :-D

Comment: @MarcioLuís If your class in `admin.py` contains `list_display = ('foo',)`, Django admin outputs `<th  class="column-foo">`. You can use `.column-foo { width: ... ; }` in your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

While this feature is implemented in vers1.6 as StvnW said, for earlier versions you can do the following:

In admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # your code here

    # specify a stylesheet just for the list view
    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('css/mymodel_list.css')}
```

In mymodel_list.css:

```
/* replace '5' with the column desired */
table#result_list td:nth-child(5) {
    width: 15em;
}
```

Specifying `table#result_list` will apply this stylesheet only to the list view and won't affect the normal admin page for this model. Also, note that while django uses `th` for the first column of the model, it still counts for a `td` child.

Comment: as my case. the `css = {'all': ('css/mymodel_list.css')}` should add a comma:  `css = {'all': ('css/mymodel_list.css', )}` to be a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11195) that addresses the need for specifying css classes for table columns in the change_list view.

That said ... in the description for the ticket there's a snippet that injects a custom stylesheet in your change_list-template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/poll_admin_changelist.css" />
{% endblock extrastyle %}
```

So you don't override the whole template, only the part (extrastyle) you need.

Now you could inject your own stylesheet and for example style your columns using the [:nth-child-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

Another option would be to wrap your specific fields in html which can be done using the [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option. Here you could define a width or class for a wrapped element. 
This does only makes sense though, if you want to control the width of limited set of fields

Comment: FWIW, that ticket is now closed as "fixed" (as of July, 2013)