# Modifying CSS for a Django Column Width

Tags: css, django

I want to make a column wider in the Django Admin change_list.

I've read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742486/how-to-give-a-column-in-the-django-admin-change-list-a-css-class), which references

"The field names in list_display will also appear as CSS classes in the HTML output, in the form of column- on each  element. This can be used to set column widths in a CSS file."

I have a column named "project."

I added this

```
th.column-project{width:50%}
```

to the end of an existing css file.

Nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the css path

#result_list > thead > tr > th.sortable.column-project

and some of the actual HTML

```
<div class="grp-module grp-changelist-results">
    <table id="result_list" cellspacing="0" class="grp-sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
             <th scope="col"  class="sortable column-project">
                 <div class="grp-text"><a href="?o=4.2">Project</a></div>
             </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Comment: That is hard to say without more info. Try to 'inspect element' the header-row of your admin table to see what styles are applied. Perhaps there is some other style that is more specific. (In Chrome, Firefox and Safari you can do: 'right click on the element > inspect element' that make sure the th.column-project is selected. Take a look at the 'styles' section to see what and if there are styles applied to this element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I inspected the css path, and excerpted some HTML.

Comment: Great! Now when you click on the 'th' in your inspector, you should see a list of styles that are applied to this th. Is your line listed? (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles#styles)

Comment: Is it the top-most entry? And in case it is Chrome, is it perhaps striped through? If its not the top-most entry and/or striped through, then there is a CSS line that is more specific than yours. In that case, make yours more specific, eg: #result_list th.column.column-project {}

Comment: It isn't striped through, and it is the top line.

Comment: got it  th.sortable.column-project .grp-text {width:500px}.  If you want to add a response, I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is somewhat listed in the comments above. For future readers of this QA:

1. Do an Inspect Element on the TH in the table to see if your CSS is applied
2. Check if anothern CSS definition is more specific and therefore overruling your own statement; if so, make yours more specific

The OP has used the grp-text class to style the column. This suggest the presence of Grappelli as skin over the admin. When you aren't using Grappelli, the class name would be .text.

Overriding the grp-text does not seem to be right because this could mess with other elements that are present in your TH. but for now you've got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from Wouter above, I realized that I needed to call out the specific class.

```
th.sortable.column-project .grp-text {width:50%}.
```